# Zorder for 3D display

Tags: z-order

I have 2 `div`:

```
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
```

Normally the 2nd is over the first. But I want the first to stay in front with zorder:

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

#one {
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    background: red;
    zorder: 2;
}

#two {
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    background: blue;
    zorder: 1;
}
```

Why does this not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is HTML and so I guess you meant `z-index`:

```
#one {
    z-index: 2;
}

#two {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Embarrassing! Thank you very much!